# Prevent Android app from crashing while reading a file that is too large

Tags: android, xamarin, memory, xamarin.android, crash

In the Xamarin Android app I'm making, I have a service that processes files. 
But when it's reading a file that is taking too much memory, it crashes the app, without any exception.

Is there a way to gracefully let the user know that this files is too large.

What I could do is determine the size of the file beforehand, but it depends on the device's memory how much it can handle, right?

Any help or suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: use a Try catch and look out for an "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" exception, when this hits you could dispose of the task to free up memory and display a message to the user.

Comment: That is not enough, because my app is consuming too much memory. Android is killing other apps, and eventually my app. So there is no time for catching errors because the OS is killing my app. :(

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see your code, so here just some advice, you could run your Xamarin.Android project with a larger heap size.

You could refer to this [question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2132/java-heap-space-outofmemoryerror-when-binding-a-big-jar). As JonathanPryor said,  you can provide the `$(JavaMaximunHeapSize)` and `$(JavaOptions)` `MSBuild` properties to let Java allocate enough memory to complete your build.

#### Method 1 :

You can do this by hand-editing your `.csproj` and adding the following section:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
</PropertyGroup>
```

#### Method 2 :

Click your project `Properties` -> `Android Options` -> `Advanced` -> `Java Max Heap Size`, set the value with "1G".

Comment: Thanks, I did that. unfortunately that did not help